# Unexpected unmapped port 80 in docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

when i run `docker ps` i am seeing port 80 unmapped on the apphub-ui container, i am expecting it to be mapped to 4200, which i also see. I dont understand why `80/tcp` is present, it is creating connection refused issues in my app.

Here is the `docker ps` output

```
docker ps                                                                                                                                                                                                                         10s +59%
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                          NAMES
22cb2b9c28d4        swimlane/apphub-ui:latest    "/usr/bin/reefer -t …"   20 seconds ago      Up 17 seconds       80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->4200/tcp   apphub_apphub-ui_1
19a78f93bfe7        swimlane/apphub-api:latest   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes        0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp         apphub_apphub-api_1
7b3478e2dcd5        mongo:3.6                    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes        0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp       apphub_mongo_1
```

My docker-compose file is as follows

```
version: '3.6'

volumes:
  mongo:

services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:3.6 
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - mongo:/data/db

  apphub-api:
    image: swimlane/apphub-api:latest
    ports: 
      - 3000:3000 
    depends_on:
      - mongo

  apphub-ui:
    image: swimlane/apphub-ui:latest
    ports: 
      - 80:4200 
    depends_on:
      - apphub-api
    environment:
      - APPHUB_API_HOST=apphub-api
```

My app runs fine if i change the mapped ports for the ui feature to `4200:4200`, and i dont see the stray unmapped 80

Comment: Can you add the `Dockerfile` for that image to the question?  (Does it `EXPOSE 80`?)

Comment: I'm having the feeling that you want to map the port 4200 on your host to the port 80 of your container. If that's the case, you should switch the values.

Comment: I agree with @DavidMaze where the Dockerfile would have `EXPOSE 80` in there. I tried to look at the source but couldn't find it online.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the feeling that you want to map the port 4200 on your host to the port 80 of your container. If that's the case, you should switch the values. i.e.

```
    ports: 
      - 4200:80
```